# jquery parse json data dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this json data

```
{
  "default": [
    [
      1325876000000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1325876000000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1325876000000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1325876000000,
      0
    ]
  ],
  "direct": [
    [
      1328196800000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1328196800000,
      100
    ],
    [
      1328196800000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1328196800000,
      0
    ]
  ],
  "Sales": [
    [
      1330517600000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1330517600000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1330517600000,
      91
    ],
    [
      1330517600000,
      0
    ]
  ],
  "Support": [
    [
      1332838400000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1332838400000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1332838400000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1332838400000,
      0
    ]
  ]
}
```

and I want to change it to this format:

```
data = [{
           label: 'defaul',
           data: the array here
       }, {
           label: 'name',
           data: the array here
       }, {
           label: 'name',
           data: the array here
       }, {
           label: 'name',
           data: the array here
       }];
```

In the past, I was doing this:

```
var thearray = result.default.
var theOtherArray = result.direct

...
..
and so on
```

It was working because I already know the name of the labels. I mean the label's name were static.

but now they are dynamic so I can't know the name of the lable.

what should I do please?

#### Edit

I know that I have to use

```
   var data = [];
    $.each(result, function (index, value) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.label = SOMETHING
    obj.data = result[label]
    data.push(obj);
}
```

but how to get the `SOMETHING`

Comment: basically you need every element to be  jsonObject which is wrapped inside a jsonArray... so you can write a method to return a jsonObject which will be added to global jsonArray...

Comment: @vivek this is the data that I have, I can't change its format

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Map the object into an array

```
var data = $.map(result, function(arr,key) {
    return {label: key, data: arr};
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MSyj9/)

Comment: is `data` the output variable , an array

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli - yes, it's exactly what you asked for.

Comment: I'd rather upvote an answer that uses Vanilla JS, but a) Array.prototype.map is only available for IE9+ (a for loop wouldn't be that bad) and b) the question does mention jQuery, so... good one.